# C# - XML, Counting the number of specific elements within other elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML which I'm loading into my C# program. What I'd like to achieve is to count the number of "army" elements within each "alliance" element.

Here's an example where each "alliance" contains three "army" elements. So the result I'd like to achieve is to have two variables with the result of 3.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<battle>
  <alliance id="0">
    <army>
      <faction>factionName</faction>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_A" />
        <general>
          <commander_record_key>commanderName</commander_record_key>
        </general>
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_A" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_A" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
    </army>
    <army>
      <faction>factionName</faction>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_A" />
        <general>
          <commander_record_key>commanderName</commander_record_key>
        </general>
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_B" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_B" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
    </army>
    <army>
      <faction>factionName</faction>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_C" />
        <general>
          <commander_record_key>commanderName</commander_record_key>
        </general>
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_C" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_C" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
    </army>
    <victory_condition>
      <kill_or_rout_enemy />
    </victory_condition>
  </alliance>
  <alliance id="1">
    <army>
      <faction>factionName</faction>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <general>
          <commander_record_key>commanderName</commander_record_key>
        </general>
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
    </army>
    <army>
      <faction>factionName</faction>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <general>
          <commander_record_key>commanderName</commander_record_key>
        </general>
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
    </army>
    <army>
      <faction>factionName</faction>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <general>
          <commander_record_key>commanderName</commander_record_key>
        </general>
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
      <unit>
        <unit_type type="unit_F" />
        <unit_capabilities>
          <special_ability>abilityName</special_ability>
        </unit_capabilities>
      </unit>
    </army>
    <victory_condition>
      <kill_or_rout_enemy />
    </victory_condition>
  </alliance>
</battle>
```

Can you help? Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Linq` to `Xml` and query for descendants and elements as below.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);


    var results = doc.Descendants("alliance")                                
                     .Select(g=> 
                             new 
                             {
                                 ID = g.Attribute("id").Value, 
                                 ArmyCount =   g.Elements("army").Count() 
                             });
```

Check this [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0TVDSA)

Comment: Thanks! Out of interest, is there another way I could do this?

Comment: There are ways, like using XmlReader and traversing each element and also using XPath queries, etc..

Comment: This approach I would say simple  and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be done with **XmlDocument** and **SelectNodes**:

```
List<int> listCount = new List<int>();
XmlDocument docXMLs = new XmlDocument();
docXML.Load("path to file.xml");

XmlNodeList listAlliance = docXML.SelectNodes("Battle/Alliance");
foreach(XmlNode nodeAlliance in listAlliance )
{
    XmlNodeList listArmy = nodAlliance.SelectNodes("Army");
    listCount.Add(listArmy.Count);
}
```

Please note that I have not tried the above code and there may be a more efficient way to do it. If the answer can be improved then I appreciate any constructive comments!